# All seems fine but I still get this: You are not currently subscribed to any Groups

Tags: contacts

Can't get customers to show up on "My contacts Dashboard" URL.

Using CIVE CRM 5.x and Drupal 7

I checked all settings, created a group,assigned customers to group, but still not showing up...on the My Contacts link :

http://localhost/crm/civicrm/user?reset=1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good screendumps, but when you add your CiviCRM version and the used CMS (I suppose Drupal, if I look to the screendumps), people have more context if they want to help you.

Comment: Your screenshots don't actually show that bruno has joined a public Group

Comment: Screenshot 1 shows the CiviCRM dashboard for brunocanada@gmail.com (Individual). 

Screenshot 2 shows a CiviCRM record for Chris Henschen or Jennifer Canal (Household)

Answer (score 4):

The dashboard only shows public groups that a user is subscribed to. You will need to set group visibility to 'Public Pages'. So you might need to update the groups that you would prefer to show up on user dashboard.

[image]

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, but that didn't work either...!